# Visual Studio 2017/2019: Conditional Compilation broken after upgrading csproj file to SDK format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, csproj, preprocessor-directive

I'm maintaining an old code base at my company and we want to implement CI/CD with Azure Pipelines. For that to work we want to output some Nuget packages as our build artifacts. Our old csproj files do not support this, so we are upgrading them to the new SDK format.

I've managed to do this successfully for some projects but now I've run into an unexpected problem. We have some conditional compilation happening with **#if DEBUG** preprocessor directives that now do not switch off when we switch to our release config. I've checked the new project file to make sure the DEBUG and TRACE constants are set appropriately between releases, but the code still does not toggle in the editor. What should I do?

**My process so far:**

- Check out the original csproj file from source control and rename it to projectname.csproj.old
- use **dotnet new classlib** to generate a new project file in the same directory.
- update this new project file to have the same assembly and package  references as the original.
- update this new project file to have the same default namespace and assembly name as the original.

**What breaks**
Switching to Release does not change which code compiles or is highlighted in the editor.

[image: The pre-processor code that is broken]

[image: My DEFINEs in the new project file]

**There is nothing particularly interesting about the project file. The folded bit is just the source control binding.**

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - the project file and a tiny bit of C# code to demonstrate the differences. (I wouldn't generally expect there to be anything in the project file for these - the defaults should work fine.)

Comment: I've now included steps to reproduce the issue. I did not edit the new project file by hand except to switch from .NET 5.0 back to .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Simply show us the content of your `csproj` file please. Screen shots like that do not help much.

Comment: You haven't actually switched to the Release configuration.  It would say "Active (Release)".  Right now you are merely editing the Release build properties.  Use the toolbar or Build > Configuration Manager to switch properly.

Comment: It used to switch it when I use the Configuration Manager, but now it is not working at all. I can switch it back and forth between Debug and Release and it will think for a minute before ultimately doing nothing.

Comment: @Zachary did you find any solution to this?

Comment: It resolved itself, but I don't understand how or why.